# How to mount my USB-C pen drive in Android 12

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, android-12, realme

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone. I've tried inserting a USB-C pen drive into the USB-C port I usually use to charge my phone. According to some websites, I should get a notification showing me that the pen drive has been mounted. However, this is not happening. In fact, the phone does not even make a beep when I insert the USB-C pen drive.

I don't even know whether the media on the pen drive is formatted, and in particular whether it is formatted for use with Android. I bought the pen drive for use with my phone. I would like to back up some internal storage or Google Drive files to the pen drive.

Here is some Termux output.

```
$ mount

/dev/block/dm-15 on / type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)
none on /dev/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
none on /dev/cpuctl type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
none on /dev/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,noprefix,release_agent=/sbin/cpuset_release_agent)
none on /dev/memcg type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
none on /dev/stune type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,schedtune)
binder on /dev/binderfs type binder (rw,relatime,max=1048576,stats=global)
adb on /dev/usb-ffs/adb type functionfs (rw,relatime)
mtp on /dev/usb-ffs/mtp type functionfs (rw,relatime)
ptp on /dev/usb-ffs/ptp type functionfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev/freezer type cgroup (rw,relatime,freezer)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime,gid=3009,hidepid=2)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,seclabel,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /mnt type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/block/dm-4 on /mnt/vendor/my_product type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-5 on /mnt/vendor/my_engineering type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-8 on /mnt/vendor/my_company type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime)
/dev/block/dm-9 on /mnt/vendor/my_carrier type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-10 on /mnt/vendor/my_region type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-7 on /mnt/vendor/my_heytap type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-6 on /mnt/vendor/my_stock type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-11 on /mnt/vendor/my_preload type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime)
/dev/block/dm-14 on /mnt/vendor/my_bigball type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-12 on /mnt/vendor/my_manifest type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/by-name/oplusreserve2 on /mnt/vendor/oplusreserve type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/oplusreserve2 on /mnt/oplus/op2 type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /mnt/installer type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/installer/0/emulated type fuse (rw,lazytime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/data/media on /mnt/installer/0/emulated/0/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/installer/0/emulated/0/Android/obb type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/installer/0/emulated/999/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/installer/999/emulated type fuse (rw,lazytime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/data/media on /mnt/installer/999/emulated/999/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/installer/999/emulated/999/Android/obb type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
tmpfs on /mnt/androidwritable type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/androidwritable/0/emulated type fuse (rw,lazytime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/data/media on /mnt/androidwritable/0/emulated/0/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/androidwritable/0/emulated/0/Android/obb type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/androidwritable/0/emulated/999/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/androidwritable/999/emulated type fuse (rw,lazytime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/data/media on /mnt/androidwritable/999/emulated/999/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/androidwritable/999/emulated/999/Android/obb type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/dev/block/by-name/protect1 on /mnt/vendor/protect_f type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/protect2 on /mnt/vendor/protect_s type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/nvdata on /mnt/vendor/nvdata type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/nvcfg on /mnt/vendor/nvcfg type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/persist on /mnt/vendor/persist type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodelalloc,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/default/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/read/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=23,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/write/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/runtime/full/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/user/0/emulated type fuse (rw,lazytime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/data/media on /mnt/user/0/emulated/0/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/user/0/emulated/0/Android/obb type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/user/0/emulated/999/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/pass_through/0/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/dev/fuse on /mnt/user/999/emulated type fuse (rw,lazytime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/data/media on /mnt/user/999/emulated/999/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/user/999/emulated/999/Android/obb type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /mnt/pass_through/999/emulated type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,multiuser,mask=7,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/dev/block/by-name/metadata on /metadata type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,data=ordered)
/dev/block/dm-16 on /vendor type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-17 on /product type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime)
overlay-overlay on /product/app type overlay (ro,seclabel,noatime,lowerdir=/mnt/vendor/my_region/app:/mnt/vendor/my_product/app:/mnt/vendor/my_heytap/app:/mnt/vendor/my_stock/app:/mnt/vendor/my_engineering/app:/product/app,override_creds=off)
overlay-overlay on /product/priv-app type overlay (ro,seclabel,noatime,lowerdir=/mnt/vendor/my_region/priv-app:/mnt/vendor/my_product/priv-app:/mnt/vendor/my_heytap/priv-app:/mnt/vendor/my_stock/priv-app:/mnt/vendor/my_engineering/priv-app:/product/priv-app,override_creds=off)
overlay-overlay on /product/lib64 type overlay (ro,seclabel,noatime,lowerdir=/mnt/vendor/my_region/lib64:/mnt/vendor/my_product/lib64:/mnt/vendor/my_heytap/lib64:/mnt/vendor/my_stock/lib64:/product/lib64,override_creds=off)
overlay-overlay on /product/lib type overlay (ro,seclabel,noatime,lowerdir=/mnt/vendor/my_region/lib:/mnt/vendor/my_product/lib:/mnt/vendor/my_heytap/lib:/mnt/vendor/my_stock/lib:/product/lib,override_creds=off)
overlay-overlay on /product/overlay type overlay (ro,seclabel,noatime,lowerdir=/mnt/vendor/my_region/overlay:/mnt/vendor/my_product/overlay:/mnt/vendor/my_heytap/overlay:/mnt/vendor/my_stock/overlay:/mnt/vendor/my_engineering/overlay:/product/overlay,override_creds=off)
overlay on /product/etc/permissions type overlay (ro,seclabel,relatime,lowerdir=/mnt/vendor/my_product/product_overlay/etc/permissions/:/product/etc/permissions/,override_creds=off)
overlay on /product/framework type overlay (ro,seclabel,relatime,lowerdir=/mnt/vendor/my_product/product_overlay/framework/:/product/framework/,override_creds=off)
/dev/block/dm-18 on /system_ext type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-3 on /odm type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
tmpfs on /apex type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755)
/dev/block/loop4 on /apex/com.android.appsearch@300000000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop4 on /apex/com.android.appsearch type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop5 on /apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim@1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop5 on /apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop6 on /apex/com.android.i18n@1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop6 on /apex/com.android.i18n type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop7 on /apex/com.android.wifi@319999900 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop7 on /apex/com.android.wifi type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-22 on /apex/com.android.extservices@341131030 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-22 on /apex/com.android.extservices type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop10 on /apex/com.android.vndk.v31@1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop10 on /apex/com.android.vndk.v31 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-23 on /apex/com.android.art@341110062 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-23 on /apex/com.android.art type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-24 on /apex/com.android.permission@341110010 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-24 on /apex/com.android.permission type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-25 on /apex/com.android.conscrypt@341110002 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-25 on /apex/com.android.conscrypt type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-26 on /apex/com.android.tzdata@313110000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-26 on /apex/com.android.tzdata type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop14 on /apex/com.android.runtime@1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop14 on /apex/com.android.runtime type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop15 on /apex/com.android.vndk.v30@1 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop15 on /apex/com.android.vndk.v30 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-27 on /apex/com.android.scheduling@340819220 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-27 on /apex/com.android.scheduling type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-28 on /apex/com.android.os.statsd@341114000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-28 on /apex/com.android.os.statsd type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-29 on /apex/com.android.media@341111002 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-29 on /apex/com.android.media type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-30 on /apex/com.android.mediaprovider@341111020 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-30 on /apex/com.android.mediaprovider type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-31 on /apex/com.android.adbd@340912202 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-31 on /apex/com.android.adbd type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-32 on /apex/com.android.media.swcodec@341111002 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-32 on /apex/com.android.media.swcodec type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-33 on /apex/com.android.neuralnetworks@341010000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-33 on /apex/com.android.neuralnetworks type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-34 on /apex/com.android.cellbroadcast@341110000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-34 on /apex/com.android.cellbroadcast type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-35 on /apex/com.android.ipsec@340914200 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-35 on /apex/com.android.ipsec type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-36 on /apex/com.android.tethering@341112070 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-36 on /apex/com.android.tethering type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/loop26 on /apex/com.google.mainline.primary.libs@311820000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-37 on /apex/com.google.mainline.primary.libs@341177000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-38 on /apex/com.android.resolv@341110000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-38 on /apex/com.android.resolv type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-39 on /apex/com.android.sdkext@341110000 type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
/dev/block/dm-39 on /apex/com.android.sdkext type ext4 (ro,dirsync,seclabel,nodev,noatime)
tmpfs on /apex/apex-info-list.xml type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755)
tmpfs on /linkerconfig type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755)
tmpfs on /linkerconfig type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755)
none on /config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/block/dm-4 on /my_product type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-5 on /my_engineering type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-8 on /my_company type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime)
/dev/block/dm-9 on /my_carrier type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-10 on /my_region type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-7 on /my_heytap type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-6 on /my_stock type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-11 on /my_preload type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime)
/dev/block/dm-14 on /my_bigball type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/dm-12 on /my_manifest type erofs (ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,cache_strategy=readaround)
/dev/block/by-name/cache on /cache type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered)
/dev/block/dm-21 on /data type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=55436,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
/dev/block/dm-21 on /data/user/0 type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=55436,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
/dev/block/by-name/oplusreserve2 on /data/persist_log/oplusreserve/media/log/shutdown type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/oplusreserve2 on /data/persist_log/oplusreserve/media/log/hang_oplus type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/oplusreserve2 on /data/persist_log/cache/factory type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/oplusreserve2 on /data/persist_log/criticallog type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/block/by-name/oplusreserve2 on /data/persist_log/oplusreserve/media/log/minidumpbackup type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
/data/incremental/MT_data_app_vmdl181/backing_store on /data/incremental/MT_data_app_vmdl181/mount type incremental-fs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,read_timeout_ms=10000,readahead=0)
/data/incremental/MT_data_app_vmdl181/backing_store on /data/app/~~Es7HI3jynEtlItXob1h4sw== type incremental-fs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,read_timeout_ms=10000,readahead=0)
tmpfs on /data_mirror type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=700,gid=1000)
/dev/block/dm-21 on /data_mirror/data_ce/null type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=55436,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
/dev/block/dm-21 on /data_mirror/data_ce/null/0 type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=55436,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
/dev/block/dm-21 on /data_mirror/data_de/null type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=55436,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
/dev/block/dm-21 on /data_mirror/cur_profiles type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=55436,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
/dev/block/dm-21 on /data_mirror/ref_profiles type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=55436,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
tmpfs on /storage type tmpfs (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2859064k,nr_inodes=714766,mode=755,gid=1000)
/dev/fuse on /storage/emulated type fuse (rw,lazytime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
/data/media on /storage/emulated/0/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
/data/media on /storage/emulated/999/Android/data type sdcardfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=1015,multiuser,mask=6,derive_gid,default_normal,unshared_obb)
```

```
$ mount|grep usb
adb on /dev/usb-ffs/adb type functionfs (rw,relatime)
mtp on /dev/usb-ffs/mtp type functionfs (rw,relatime)
ptp on /dev/usb-ffs/ptp type functionfs (rw,relatime)
```

Alternatively, how can I format or copy files to my USB pen drive from Android?

Thanks.

My pen drive is not showing in file manager:

[image: file manager]

EDIT: I have searched for OTG (on-the-go) settings in the settings, and have enabled it, as shown below (not sure if this is the USB OTG or something else, can someone please help me, thanks).

[image: OTG image]

However, even after snacking this option I cannot see my pen drive in the stock Files app that came with my phone.

Comment: https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/sd-card-file-system-for-android.html Please check it and format accordingly, if needed, using another device.

Comment: Ok so Android uses FAT32 or exFAT file system. But how do I format the file system on my USB stick (not SD card), from Android? Is it possible. The tutorial does not say how to do it.

Comment: Can you please help me? I don't have a computer, but I want to transfer some files from my phone to USB.

Comment: You first have to check if USB OTG is enabled at all: https://www.realme.com/in/support/kw/doc/2072113 If it is enabled and you don't get any notification when inserting the pen drive then that pen drive can not be used by your phone. Connected to a PC it may be possible it reformat and check the pen drive but as you don't have access to a PC this is not an option for you.

Comment: Hi. I'm not using an OTG cable (as a matter of fact I do not have one). I'm plugging the USB C pen drive directly into the phone. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Why can't I format the pen drive from the smartphone?